# Visual Studio Regex Find and Replace `new vtk[...]()` to `vtk[...].New()`

Tags: regex, replace, visual-studio-2015, find

I am trying to replace all the places where we instantiate a `VTK` object like this: `new vtk[...]();` with this pattern: `vtk[...].New()`.

The Find regex I'm using is:  `new vtk\w`, but I don't know what the replacement regex should be.  How would I do this?

#### For Example

`... = new vtkPoints();` should turn into `... = vtkPoints.New();`

Comment: Are you sure your pattern matches what you want? Please provide real-life examples with expected output.

Comment: I guess not since you are asking that question.  But the results in the Find Window look right.  Why do you ask?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, did that provide the additional information you are looking for?

Comment: Well, I'd use `\bnew vtk(\w+)\(\);` and replaced with `vtk$1.New();` (see [demo here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbnew+vtk(%5cw%2b)%5c(%5c)%3b&i=%3d+new+vtkPoints()%3b&r=vtk%241.New()%3b)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find `new vtk\[(.+)\]\(\);`
Replace with `vtk[$1].New();`

**Explanation:**

- We must escape characters in the FIND string, if they are regex operators. Thus, `\(` means capture a `(`, `\]` means capture a `]` etc..
- We capture the content using `(.+)` meaning capture at least one of any character (`.` matches all characters), so that we can use it in the replace string.
- in the REPLACE string, we use `$1`, which means the content of the first capture group

**Edit:** if you want to support `new vtk();` without anything inside the parantheses, replace `(.+)` with `(.*)`, which means at least 0, instead of at least 1

**Edit 2:** misread your question a bit, you need `new vtk(\w+)\(\)` with `vtk$1.New()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  Unfortunately, this regex: `new vtk\[(.+)\]\(\);` did not find anything

Comment: Edited it, didn't see that the change was in the class name (e.g. vtkPoints)

Comment: Thank you!  StackOverflow says I can accept your answer in 5 minutes

Comment: *misread your question a bit* and decided to copy Wiktor's suggestion. Well, that is not nice, you posted `new vtk(.+)\(\)`, why not stick to that?

Comment: Haven't seen your comment, sorry if you feel like I copied off you

Comment: No, I do not feel like that. I just wonder why you *changed* to the answer that is almost like mine?

Comment: Because I reread the question after he said it failed, and realized I was a dumbass

Comment: Ok, two points: 1) you do not need to escape `]` outside of a character class, 2) *`.` matches all characters* is not true *especially* when it comes to VS search and replace (it does not match a linebreak symbol).